# Display data from SQL db in WebMatrix using multiple select boxes

Tags: c#, sql, webmatrix

I just start with C# and I'm still learning this stuff. I try to display data using multiple WHERE clauses populated from select boxes.
I found problem with if(Request.QueryString["..."].IsEmpty() )

This is working only for first select box. If this box is selected all next boxes selection is omitted. If the first box is not selected, no data is displayed. How I can solve this?

Here is my code:

```
var db = Database.Open("Eason");
var Warranty = Request["Warranty"];
var EbookM = Request["EbookM"];    

if (IsPost) 
{
    Warranty = Request["Warranty"];
    if (Warranty.IsEmpty()) {
       selectQ = "SELECT * FROM E_Reader";}

    Warranty = Request["EbookM"];
    if (EbookM.IsEmpty()) {
       selectQ = "SELECT * FROM E_Reader";}


    if(Request.QueryString["Warranty"].IsEmpty() ) {
    selectQ = "SELECT * FROM E_Reader";
    searchTerm1 = Request.QueryString["Warranty"];
    searchTerm2 =Request.QueryString["EbookM"];

}

var selectedData1 = db.Query(selectQ, searchTerm1, searchTerm2);
var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData1, defaultSort: "Ebook_Model", rowsPerPage: 10);
```

Comment: I don't understand some things in your code: which value could have `selectQ` apart of `"SELECT * FROM E_Reader"`? Do you expect that other pages pass values to this page via QueryString? By the way, the statement `Warranty = Request["EbookM"];` should probably be corrected in `EbookM = Request["EbookM"];`. Maybe some good tutorials as [link](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/180/Displaying-Search-Results-In-A-WebGrid) and [link](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/192/Transferring-Data-Between-ASP.NET-Web-Pages) could help.

Comment: Sorry, I had to be really tired yesterday. I know this code was a nightmare. Here is newer version but still not working.                  var Warranty = Request["Warranty"];
    var Made = Request["Made"];
    var db = Database.Open("Eason");
       var searchTerm = "";
       var selectCommand1 = "SELECT * FROM EMADE";
       var selectedEbook1 = db.Query(selectCommand1, searchTerm);
    var sqlQ = "SELECT * FROM E_Reader WHERE In_Warranty LIKE @0 or Ebook_Made LIKE @1";
    
    var selectedData = db.Query(sqlQ, Warranty,Made);
    
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData);

Comment: I checked these links but this till not working for me.

Comment: separately both WHERE clauses works fine but when I use them together all data is displayed.

Comment: Sorted :). There should be WHERE.....AND..... instead of OR

Answer (score 0):

Sorted :). There should be WHERE.....AND..... instead of OR – Thhhe just now

Final code is:

```
var db = Database.Open("Eason");
var sqlQ = "SELECT * FROM E_Reader WHERE In_Warranty LIKE @0 AND Ebook_Made LIKE @1";
var Warranty = "%" + Request["Warranty"] + "%";
var Made = "%" + Request["Made"] + "%";

var selectedData = db.Query(sqlQ, Warranty, Made);

var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData, defaultSort: "Ebook_Made");
```

Comment: Thank you. I really did not think about this. How I can prevent from this?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code, you're fine! In my defence, the formatting threw me off!